# Writing to a .wav file

Tags: python, audio

I have used the write function from scipy.io.wavfile to generate a .wav file.

```
final_out = np.int16(stereo_out/np.max(np.abs(stereo_out)) * 32767)
write('final.wav', fs, final_out)
```

Is there any alternate function for write that allows more than 32767 samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **not such limitation in the number of samples** that can be written to a a wav file with `scipy.io.wavfile`. The [actual limitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV#Limitations) on the number of samples is 2^32 (4,294,967,296), but it comes from the fact that the header stores the number of samples as a 32-bit unsigned integer.

The WAV format, however, stores the amplitude of each sample in 16-bits.

With a signed integer of 16-bits, you can only store numbers in the range [-32768, 32767] inclusive, you'll need to scale your signal accordingly to fit that range.

You can think of that number as a fraction (ratio) of the highest amplitude that your system can produce.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! :)

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [wave module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html) in Python's Standard Library. It may allow you to write more than 32767 samples, but I am unsure as to what limitations you may come across while trying to use it.